# Jquery UI slider selector (cannot locate with jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, reactjs

I have the following DOM:

[image]

Within this list are (two) jquery UI sliders, each slider has two nobs:
[image]

I would like to loop through the sliders in the list and change the value of the nobs. I am havinga a hard time locating these sliders with jquery. Here is the code I have thus far:

```
this.state.exceptionsEdit.forEach(function (exp, index){

      $('#exception-list-edit:nth-child('+index+')').find('.ui-slider').slider("values", 0, Date.parse(this.state.exceptionsEdit[index].start)/1000)
      $('#exception-list-edit:nth-child('+index+')').find('.ui-slider').slider("values", 1, Date.parse(this.state.exceptionsEdit[index].end)/1000)
}
```

How do I select and update all of these ui slider nobs properly with jQuery?

Comment: show your code where you creating that sliders

Comment: and please, instead of pasting a screenshot, paste your `html` code. this way it will be much easier to understand your problem